# How do I wait on output from sysfs?

Tags: c, linux

I tried the obvious (see below), but it does not catch new output to /var/log/syslog. I'm sure there is an answer somewhere already, but I have not been able to find it.

Here is my code (my best guess how to do this):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // provides fopen()
#include <unistd.h>  // provides sleep()


int main() {

    // *** This is failing to pick up new output on /var/log/syslog. I'm not sure
    // how to do this properly.

    // Open a read file handle on /sys/kernel/tracing/trace and wait for data to
    // appear there. When it does, echo it to the screen. This is essentially an
    // implementation of "tail -f /sys/kernel/tracing/trace".

    //FILE *fp = fopen("/sys/kernel/tracing/trace", "r");
    FILE *fp = fopen("/var/log/syslog", "r");
    char c;

    if (fp != NULL) {
        printf("Opened the file successfully. Waiting...\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // Check every second and output whatever is in the buffer.
    while(1) {
        c = fgetc(fp);

        // We get back -1 when there is nothing to read.
        if (c != -1) {
            printf("%c", c);
        } else {
            printf(".");  fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: inotify (7)

Comment: Maybe you just want to run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` instead of writing your own software.  If you really want to write your own software, one idea would be to run `strace tail -f /var/log/syslog` and see what it does, or read the source code of `tail`.

Comment: What does /var/log/syslog have to do with sysfs?

Comment: It is a similar filesystem that is easier to generate output on. Am I missing something?

Comment: @StackOOverflow *Am I missing something?* Yes.  `/var/log/syslog` is going to be on a persistent, "real" filesystem such as `XFS` or `ext4`.  [`sysfs` is nothing like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call clearerr(fp) to clear the feof indicator:

```
// Check every second and output whatever is in the buffer.
while(1) {
    c = fgetc(fp);

    // We get back -1 when there is nothing to read.
    if (c != -1) {
        printf("%c", c);
    } else {
        printf(".");  fflush(stdout); 
        if(feof(fp)) clearerr(fp);  // <-- clear the feof indicator
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very concise and it works. : )